# How can I change background image via Javascript code in Carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a Slider object which contains SliderImageUrl for the image.

Here is my c# code to show the slider list in HTML part.

```
ViewBag.Slider = db.Slider.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.SliderId);
```

I want to change a background image when I click the previous or forward button in the carousel.

I write a template js code to handle with it but I have no idea about other things.

1. When I open the page, the first slider is shown. When I click the previous button, I want to show the last slider' image in the background image in the section part.
2. When I show the last slider background image then I click the forward button, it shows the first slider.
3. Changing the process will be done when I click the previous or forward button.

How can I handle with this process?

Here is my `HTML` code which is shown below.

```
<section id="hero" class="d-flex justify-cntent-center align-items-center">
    <div id="heroCarousel" class="container carousel carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="5000">


        @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.Slider)
        {

           <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="carousel-container">
                        <h2 class="animate__animated animate__fadeInDown">@item.SliderAd</h2>
                        <p class="animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">@item.SliderKisaAciklama</p>
                        <a href="#lastnews" class="btn-get-started animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">Sayfaya Git</a>
                    </div>
          </div>
          }
    
            <a id="previous_button" class="carousel-control-prev" href="#heroCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bx bx-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
    
            <a id="forward_button" class="carousel-control-next" href="#heroCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bx bx-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Here is my `javascript` code which is shown below.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var myArray = [];

        @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.Slider)
        {
            @:myArray.push(item);
        }

        var el = document.getElementById("previous_button");
        if (el) {
            addEventListener("click", switchImage1());
        }
        var el2 = document.getElementById("forward_button");
        if (el2) {
            addEventListener("click", switchImage2());
        }
    });

    function switchImage1(imageUrl) {
        $('#hero').css('background-image', "url('+ imageUrl +')");
    }
    function switchImage2(imageUrl) {
        $('#hero').css('background-image', "url('+ imageUrl +')");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Change ```$('#hero').css('background-image', "url('+ imageUrl +')");``` to ```$('#hero').css('background-image', "url('"+ imageUrl +"')");```

Comment: @prettyInPink How can I send the parameter imageUrl to `switchImage1` or `switchImage2` function? I listed some items to show how to implement the process.

Comment: @prettyInPink I wait your response.

Comment: Hi , carousel has that feature already implemented why you need to do that in js ?

Comment: @Swati Carousel only covers its own div area. I want to cover the background image in section div covering the carousel. How can I do that? I edited my post.

Comment: @Swati I want to reach section div in foreach loop to change background.

Comment: so `section` should have bg image from next slide ? from where `imageUrl` coming ?

Comment: @Swati You're right. Slider has a image attribute and I send it as a list to html via this code `ViewBag.Slider = db.Slider.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.SliderId);`

Comment: can you show output of `myArray` as i am much not familiar with c#?

Comment: @Swati There is also a problem. I have no idea how to assign all list to javascript array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232519/discussion-between-swati-and-tony-brand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution which is shown below.

```
$('#hero').css('background-image', "url(" + $(".carousel-item:eq(0)").data("image") + ")");
$("#heroCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
$('#hero').css('background-image', "url(" + $(".carousel-item.active").data("image") + ")");
})
```